# Programmatically Create Grid with Custom Element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create a grid programmatically and appending a custom control as a child to the grid as row 0 column 0 out of a 2x2 matrix. To make matters more tricky, I'm using the MVVM design pattern. Heres some code to help everyone get the idea:

**App.xaml.cs**

```
base.OnStartup(e);
var viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
mainWindow.GridWindows = viewModel.Window.GridWindows;
```

**MainWindowViewModel - method returns the GridWindows.**

```
    private Grid CreateGrid()
    {
        Grid grid = new Grid();

        // Create column definitions.
        ColumnDefinition columnDefinition1 = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition columnDefinition2 = new ColumnDefinition();
        columnDefinition1.Width = new GridLength(640);
        columnDefinition2.Width = new GridLength(640);

        // Create row definitions.
        RowDefinition rowDefinition1 = new RowDefinition();
        RowDefinition rowDefinition2 = new RowDefinition();
        rowDefinition1.Height = new GridLength(340);
        rowDefinition2.Height = new GridLength(340);

        // Attached definitions to grid.
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnDefinition1);
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnDefinition2);
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDefinition1);
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDefinition2);

        // Create preview window.
        Border border = new Border();
        border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(20);
        border.Padding = new Thickness(8);
        border.SetResourceReference(Control.BackgroundProperty, "PreviewWindow");

        MediaRTSPElement previewElement = new MediaRTSPElement();
        previewElement.Name = "RTSPStreamPlayer";
        previewElement.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;
        previewElement.Source = "rtsp://192.100.100.22/media/video1";
        previewElement.VideoRenderer = VideoRendererType.EnhancedVideoRenderer;
        previewElement.LoadedBehavior = WPFEVR.DirectShow.Players.MediaState.Play;
        previewElement.SpeedRatio = 0.5;

        //border.Child = previewElement;

        // Add preview window.
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            grid.Children.Add(previewElement as UIElement);
            Grid.SetColumn(previewElement, i);
            Grid.SetRow(previewElement, i);
            break;
        }

        return grid;
    }
```

**And the XAML Markup that the grid should assign to**

```
<Grid x:Name="GridWindows"></Grid>
```

The problem is my custom control does not appear in the grid layout, heres the xaml code that does it without code-behind, and this does work:

```
        <Grid x:Name="GridWindows">
            <!--<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="640" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="640" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="340" />
                <RowDefinition Height="340" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border BorderThickness="20" Padding="8" Background="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=PreviewWindow}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                <evr:MediaRTSPElement x:Name="RTSPStreamPlayer"
                              Stretch="UniformToFill"
                              VideoRenderer="EnhancedVideoRenderer"
                              LoadedBehavior="Play"
                              Source="rtsp://192.100.100.22/media/video1"
                              SpeedRatio="0.5" />
            </Border>
            <Border BorderThickness="20" Padding="8" Background="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=PreviewWindow}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                <evr:MediaRTSPElement x:Name="RTSPStreamPlayer2"
                              Stretch="UniformToFill"
                              VideoRenderer="EnhancedVideoRenderer"
                              LoadedBehavior="Play"
                              Source="rtsp://192.100.100.78/media/video1"
                              SpeedRatio="0.5" />
            </Border>
            <Border BorderThickness="20" Padding="8" Background="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=PreviewWindow}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
                <evr:MediaRTSPElement x:Name="RTSPStreamPlayer3"
                              Stretch="UniformToFill"
                              VideoRenderer="EnhancedVideoRenderer"
                              LoadedBehavior="Play"
                              Source="rtsp://192.100.100.78/media/video1"
                              SpeedRatio="0.5" />
            </Border>
            <Border BorderThickness="20" Padding="8" Background="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=PreviewWindow}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                <evr:MediaRTSPElement x:Name="RTSPStreamPlayer4"
                              Stretch="UniformToFill"
                              VideoRenderer="EnhancedVideoRenderer"
                              LoadedBehavior="Play"
                              Source="rtsp://192.100.100.22/media/video1"
                              SpeedRatio="0.5" />
            </Border>-->
        </Grid>
```

Any ideas as to why programmatic code isn't working?

Comment: How are you adding newly created grid to your view?

Comment: Standard mvvm design call the MainWindowViewModel constructor to pull in the appropriate properties, the GridWindows property stores the returned grid from the method above - window = new Models.MainWindow { Layout = 1, GridWindows = CreateGrid() };

Comment: It looks like there are quite a few things wrong with your code. In MVVM you shouldn't be creating UI controls in the ViewModel. What was the matter with the way you had it - defining the grid in the xaml?

Comment: I assumed thats where I messed up, was MVVM, but I'm not doing it through xaml because the grid can change based on 4 buttons that change it's layout and essentially pulls in a video stream per grid location.

Comment: Seems to be my custom control, I removed the ui method out of the viewmodel, your right it doesn't belong there... but I have it working to displays elements, my custom control seems to be the culprit... but weird that it works in xaml and not in code behind. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, some values aren't being set where I had set them up initially through dependency properties, have to tweak it, thanks for your everyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you're creating `Grid` in the xaml you can't later set it in code. Grid (instance) is already in visualtree. Overwriting variable won't do any effect. You should set your `Grid` as content of xaml defined control. I'm guessing that your code looks like this:

Code:

```
this.GridWindows = createdGrid;
```

Xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="GridWindows"></Grid>
```

In code you should have something like this:

```
this.GridWindows.Children.Add(createdGrid);
```