# how to add controls to a wpf grid panel using xaml at runtime based on some events like selecting a context menu item

Tags: wpf, xaml

Hi i am new to wpf and i want to add controls in a grid using xaml at runtime based on some events like selecting a contextmenuitem is it possible if yes please provide some code snippets.
I want to it in xaml only.

Comment: no as of now i don't know its like i am having one grid containing 3 rows in 2nd row i will be having one button once i click on that button, i want to add one text box in grid.row=0

Comment: You should consider binding in XAML, over creating in C# (as we did in WinForms). More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002604/xaml-or-c-sharp-code-behind and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404943/programmatically-create-grid-with-custom-element

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add controls at runtime using XAML only, but you can set control's Visibility using EventTriggers:

```
<StackPanel>
        <Button Content="First">       
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="{x:Static Button.ClickEvent}">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Second" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>                        
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="Second"  Content="Second" Visibility="Collapsed"/>            
    </StackPanel>
```

I think that this approach is awful, but it works :)
It is much more simpler to add control from the code-behind.